# Custom web component that acts like a link (anchor tag)

Tags: web-component

I created a custom web component button, that has a `href` attribute. If one clicks on the button, I use Javascript to navigate to its own `href` attribute.

Unfortunately, after migrating a large code base of anchor tags that were styled to look like buttons, I have realized that my custom web component has many disadvantages:

1. There is no right-click link context menu.

   - E.g. one can't right-click and select open in a tab.
2. Can't CTRL+click to open link in new tab.
3. Can't middle-click to open in a new tab.

Items 2-3 could be fixed in Javascript, but item 1 is not trivial.

I did some research about extending built-in elements using the `is` keyword, but that just took me down a rabbit hole of bug reports of Safari refusing to implement the web component spec for extending HTML elements.

Is there any way to add an anchor tag's behaviour to a custom web component, like via a mixin?

Comment: That sounds you are talking about polymer and not customElements. Are you using a baseelement like `LitElement` (successor of polymer)?

Comment: Not using any framework, using vanilla JS.

Comment: I would rather go the other way and use an anchor tag and style it like a button. And what is actually the point of having a custom element, if you only want just a style and no behavior?

Comment: Thats what I migrated away from. It's not trivial styling, solid buttons, outlined buttons, various hovver effects, submit buttons with various functionality, various colours and sizes. The styling gets pretty crazy. Cleaned it all up with a web component and encapsulated styles, but hit this issue at the end.

Comment: Ok, I understand.

Comment: Just use a native anchor element inside your custom element's shadow DOM. See the second code example in my answer. That way you get an all-native behaviour, along with the style encapsulation you are looking for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use [@ungap/custom-elements](https://github.com/ungap/custom-elements) polyfill and you're good to go with Safari as well as even Internet Explorers, both with customized built-in elements, and autonomous custom elements.

Then an implementation could look like this:

```js
class CustomAnchor extends HTMLAnchorElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.addEventListener('click', this.click.bind(this));
  }
  
  click(event) {
    if (event.getModifierState('Control') || event.getModifierState('Meta')) return; // allow control-click or cmd-click (mac) to work as usual
    event?.preventDefault();
    console.log(this.href);
    // do whatever you like here
  }
}

customElements.define('custom-anchor', CustomAnchor, { extends: 'a' });
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/@ungap/custom-elements"></script>
<a is="custom-anchor" href="https://google.com">Custom google anchor</a>
```

The downside of extending built-ins is that there is no shadowDOM that allows style encapsulation. If you need that, instead go with an autonomous custom element and use a native anchor tag (or even your extended built-in HTMLAnchorElement) internally:

```js
const styles = `
  a { color: red; }
  a:hover { background-color: yellow; }
`;

class CustomAnchor extends HTMLElement {
  
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
    const style = document.createElement('style');
    style.textContent = styles;
    this.anchor = document.createElement('a');
    this.shadowRoot.append(style, this.anchor);
  }
  
  static get observedAttributes() { return ['link', 'text']; }  
  
  attributeChangedCallback(attr, oldVal, newVal) {
    if (oldVal === newVal) return; // nothing changed
    switch (attr) {
      case 'link':
        if (newVal) this.anchor.href = newVal;
        else this.anchor.removeAttribute('href');
        break;
      case 'text':
        this.anchor.textContent = newVal ?? '';
        break;
      default:
    }
  }
}

customElements.define('custom-anchor', CustomAnchor);
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/@ungap/custom-elements"></script>
<custom-anchor link="https://google.com" text="Google Search"></custom-anchor>
```

[image: Context Menu - works.]

If you prefer (e.g. for screenreaders and SEO-reasons) to have the link text as the element's content, throw in a default `<slot>`:

```js
const styles = `
  a { color: red; }
  a:hover { background-color: yellow; }
`;

class CustomAnchor extends HTMLElement {
  
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
    const style = document.createElement('style');
    style.textContent = styles;
    this.anchor = document.createElement('a');
    const slot = document.createElement('slot');
    this.anchor.appendChild(slot);
    this.shadowRoot.append(style, this.anchor);
  }
  
  static get observedAttributes() { return ['link']; }  
  
  attributeChangedCallback(attr, oldVal, newVal) {
    if (oldVal === newVal) return; // nothing changed
    switch (attr) {
      case 'link':
        if (newVal) this.anchor.href = newVal;
        else this.anchor.removeAttribute('href');
        break;
      default:
    }
  }
}

customElements.define('custom-anchor', CustomAnchor);
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/@ungap/custom-elements"></script>
<custom-anchor link="https://google.com">Google Search</custom-anchor>
```

Comment: The question was about styling a link and encapsulating those styles in the component.

Comment: That was one part of the question. But I'll add that as well.

Comment: Wow thanks for the wealth of information, this answer is better than what I could of hoped for. Theres a few approaches for me to try, but I am liking the `go with an autonomous custom element and use a native anchor tag` approach.

Comment: Hopefully there are no side effects of using an anchor tag with no href.

Comment: There is just one issue, if I add padding to `wc-button`, it neds to be added to the link, but instead it applies it to the `host`. Is there anyway around this? (make :host padding apply to child anchor in shadowRoot)

Comment: @run_the_race To make elements inside the shadow DOM accept styling from the outside, use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::part

Comment: Web component styling is a major problem. An inline style may be rejected by a CSP. And an external style may cause flickering.

Answer (score 2):

Just wrap a link and style it as button.

Clicking on links in codesnippets do not work, thus I created also a codepen for it. https://codepen.io/waxolunist/pen/ZEXwQYa

```html
<script type="module">
import {
  LitElement,
  html,
  css
} from "https://unpkg.com/lit-element/lit-element.js?module";

class MyLinkButton extends LitElement {
  
 static get properties() {
    return {
      href: { type: String, reflect: true },
    };
  }
  
  static get styles() {
    return css`
    .button {
      background-color: #4CAF50; /* Green */
      border: none;
      color: white;
      padding: 15px 32px;
      text-align: center;
      text-decoration: none;
      display: inline-block;
      font-size: 16px;
    }

    .button:hover {background-color: #220440}

    .button:active {
        background-color: #230545;
        box-shadow: 0 5px #e1d5ed;
        transform: translateY(4px);
    }
    `;
  }

  render() {
    return html`
      <a class="button" href="${this.href}" target="_blank">
      <slot></slot>
      </a>
    `;
  }
}

customElements.define("my-linkbutton", MyLinkButton);
</script>
<my-linkbutton href="http://example.com">SOME TEXT</my-linkbutton>
```

Sorry, if unpkg is slow again.

Comment: This question is about vanilla webcomponents. You even asked for it in the comments and got this response. So why are you suggesting `LitElement`? I just hope it's not that you cannot create native webcomponents without it.

Comment: @connexo The principal is the same. Add a property, render a link and add styling. He tried it without framework, doesn't mean, that he cannot add a very small dependency or abstract from my answer and implement in its own way.

Comment: @connexo At that speed - no I cannot create customelements without a little helper framework. I asked what he is using. The opener didn't ask for not using a framework. Read exactly.

Comment: Not asking for a framework and answering "Not using any framework, using vanilla JS." asks for solutions "not using a framework".

Comment: @connexo Doesn't change the principle of the solution. Answering a question is not programming the entire thing. And asking for no framework would be formulating a question. But looking at your solution and how complicated it is to build html, should let prefer anybody with a mind my solution over yours. Besides it is not a framework, but a library.